# Will an anti possession tattoo trap or expel a demon?

Tags: supernatural

(I have just reached season 8, so please no spoilers)

I was wondering what would happen if a person gets the anti possession tattoo while being possessed, will the demon be trapped or expelled?
Of course usually the Demon would be in charge, so they wouldn't let their vessel be tattooed, but what if the human could overcome the demon for a period of time?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Supernatural wiki, the [anti-possesion tattoo](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-possession_tattoo) only wards off demons, ie it protects from possession, but it doesn't necessarily expel the demon once it has taken over a person. Specifically, the wiki says that:

> It features a pentagram, or endless knot, which is the reason why it
>   protects those who wear this symbol. The only people known to have
>   this symbol tattooed on their bodies are Sam and Dean Winchester and
>   Sera Siege.

So, probably the answer is we don't know as very few people have had it in the series and it doesn't seem to have been used in that manner.